# Images have dotted bottom border

Tags: support, images

There is some CSS affecting images in SO Meta posts (not in SO main site posts):

```
.wmd-preview a, .post-text a, .comment-copy a {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #444;
}
```

It is adding a dotted bottom border to all images I've seen:

> [image]

There should be one right ^there^ below the image as well.

I must have recropped my images five times in different programs and formats before realizing that this bottom border wasn't coming from me.  I thought I was going crazy.  Is this bottom border intentional?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I just figured this out as I hit submit.  Rather obvious.  The questions are embedded as links by default.  Compare these:

- With link (`[![enter image description here][2]][2]`)

  > [image]
- Without link (`![enter image description here][3]`)

  > [image]

Pretty silly of me to miss this.  As long as a duplicate doesn't exist, I suppose I'll leave this here for other folks searching for "image bottom border" on SO Meta.

Comment: I still find the dotted line annoying and wouldn't miss it if it went away. Users normally expect (and be confirmed by their cursor changing on hover) that clicking an image will enlarge it even without that line, which, by the way, isn't a very clear indicator of the picture being a link anyway.